# Jquery click event not retaining changes after link click in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing an application by using asp.net mvc 5.Basically, the structure of my template is such that it has a master view that contains a number of links in the form of dropdown (treeview), Now what I'm trying is that whenever the user clicks the link, it will execute that particular controller's action, this way :

```
<li class="treeview">
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>Basic Setup</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">                           
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Department", "Index", "Departments")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Designation", "Index", "Designations")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Location", "Index", "Locations")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Payment Mode", "Index", "PaymentModes")</li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

the above is the code of a dropdown, which simply redirects to a particular controller's action, this above code is associated with a jquery click event that just modifies the parent li tag class from (treeview) to (active treeview) and the child li tag class by adding a class (active), note that I want to display that link as an active link if the user clicks it, by using the code below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "aside.main-sidebar ul li ul li a", function (e) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
            $(this).parents("li.treeview").removeClass().addClass("active treeview");
        });
    });     
</script>
```

Everything works fine but the point where I'm having trouble is that when the user clicks the link it goes to the controller's action, renders the view, but the whole page gets refreshed, and it looks like when the link is clicked, it executes the jquery click event (adds active class) and then it goes to the controller renders the view and the whole view is refreshed and then displays it, below is the action, just for convenience :

```
public class DepartmentsController : Controller
{
    private HrAndPayroll db = new HrAndPayroll();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Departments.Where(x => x.SystemCode == SysCode).ToList());     
    }
}
```

How do I cope with this situation because I haven't experienced it before, also I'm new with asp.net mvc, your experience will be deeply appreciated. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: you can just change the class of the li to active to particular page. do not need to handle click event

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers , can you please share some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply use the values contained in ViewContext.RouteData, namely the Action and Controller values. We could build on what you currently have with something like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "Departments" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Department", "Index", "Departments")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "Designations" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Designation", "Index", "Designations")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "Locations" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Location", "Index", "Locations")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "PaymentModes" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Payment Mode", "Index", "PaymentModes")</li>
</ul>
```

It's not pretty in code, but it'll get the job done and allow you to extract your menu into a partial view if you like. There are ways to do this in a much cleaner way, but since for just getting started, it's suffice.

Hope this will works for you!

Comment: Whao, better one, Thank you so much, that's the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a little jquery script on each of the Views that will make that link active when the page has loaded.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    $(this).parents("li.treeview").removeClass().addClass("active treeview");
});
</script
```

It may be a little less flexible but at least you can specify what link should be active when the user is on a particular View.